# select distinct two columns with random id

Tags: sql, random, db2, distinct

I would like to get distinct record of each Design and type with random id of each record
It is not possible to use

```
select distinct Design, Type, ID from table
```

It will return all values
This is structure of my table

```
Design | Type | ID
old chair 1
old table 2
old chair 3
new chair 4
new table 5
new table 6
newest chair 7
```

Possible result

```
Design | Type | ID
old table 2
old chair 3
new chair 4
new table 6
newest chair 7
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't matter which one, you can always take the maximum\minimum one:

```
SELECT design,type,max(ID)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY design,type
```

This won't be randomly, it will always take the maximum\minimum one but it doesn't seems like it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select *
from (
select *, row_number() over (partition by Design,Type order by id desc) rowID
from @tab
) x
where rowID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one helps you :

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Design, Type, ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Design, 
                                                   Type ORDER BY id DESC) rid
    FROM table
)
SELECT Design, Type, ID FROM CTE WHERE rid = 1 ORDER BY ID
```